# how can I separate these 2 fingers?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I managed to sculpt a hand but the ring and middle finger are united half way.. How can I make a distance between them? My .blend file is here:
[image]

Here are some pics: [image]

This is the side view of the problematic part in edit mode
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not united. They are overlapping.
Well, easy ... not really, no. First you need to select the finger you want to edit. I did from the inside, which I think, is much easier.
Then you can rotate, move, scale the selected nodes/faces. Proportional editing might come in handy. Also, using the 3D-Cursor at the nuckle might help with rotations.

You could also select the middle finger fist, then hide those faces `[h]` to work on the ring finger - or vice versa. Unhide all faces (in edit mode) `[ALT]+[h]`.
Hint: when you hide faces, switching to sculpt mode will keep those faces hidden.

Also, while you're in edit mode: create a vertex group of each finger. This makes further selections and rigging easier.

[image: Left, selected ring finger. Right, not selected middle finger. They are overlapping at the "first visible" bone.]
Viewed from the inside. Left, selected ring finger. Right, not selected middle finger. They are overlapping at the "first visible" bone.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to do this. Do you manually select all faces of 1 finger ? Also, for animation I should retopologize the hand, the actual geometry is bad, isn't it ?

Comment: "Do you manually select all faces of 1 finger ", well, yes and no. There's that "Select linked flat faces", which helps a lot! Also, with the `[c]`-tool (cirlce-selection). Especially where you have that overlap - you'll need to select some faces on both sides.

I don't do rigging and such animations, sorry ;-) But, if you ask me, I'd say you got a lot of faces! The geometry itself is a very detailed hand!!

Comment: About selection: You can select an edge loop at the root of the finger, and "Mark Seam" (U). Now you can just hover the mouse over the finger and "Select Linked" with key (L). In the options popup (F9 if you missed it) you can limit the selection to the seam.
I would retopologize the mesh for animation and texturing. Geometry is not bad but way too dense for animation.

Comment: Thank you both!